# Commands vs keys/values for setting up a document: what an own document class should provide?

Tags: macros, best-practices, package-writing, documentclass-writing, options

This question somehow extends the question "[Package option vs setup command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/434514/18401)".

I'm currently writing a class dedicated to students reports for both academic projects and internships. This class provides a `\reportsetup` command that lets the user setting things up via keys/values.

For example, one thing that can be set up is the company's name of the internship. It appears that this could be done both:

- via a command: `\companyname{⟨name⟩}`,
- via a `key=value`: `\reportsetup{companyname = ⟨name⟩}`,

and this, whether the class considers the company's name mandatory or not: both commands and keys may be mandatory or optional.

This is just an example but potentially applies to all commands all classes (or packages) could provide.

What would be the best between these two  practices?

Comment: Personally, I always use setup macro for mandatory (else it will not compile) definitions and key-value-interfaces for anything else (mandatory, if feature used, optional, etc.). But I think it also comes down to personal preference.

Comment: @TeXnician How do you deal with commands with more than one mandatory argument? For instance, does a command such as `\advisor{⟨first name⟩}{⟨last name⟩}` become a key-value such as `advisor = {⟨first name⟩}{⟨last name⟩}`?

Comment: If the advisor is not mandatory for compilation I would make it a key-value-option, yes. But with multiple mandatory arguments I have previously gone the subkeying route (something along the lines of `advisor = {firstname=John, lastname=Doe}`) which might not be optimal. That said, if there is no need to split these information I do not do it (if I know advisor will only be printed on title page then it is a user-formatted field, so only one), and I would recommend reducing the amount of multiple-mandatory-argument fields.

Comment: `advisor = {firstname=John, lastname=Doe}`: non optimal because "too much"? I need to split the information (first vs last names) because, in French, it is common to typeset the last name in small caps.

Comment: Non-optimal because too much and because names are hard (what about middle names etc.?). If I could, I would use biblatex's name detection on that. But still, if I had to do it, I would probably choose that way again.

Comment: @TeXnician Using the `biblatex`'s features for names is what I did for two classes of mine (where bibliographies were needed anyway) :) For this new class, bibliographies are quite optional and I'm reluctant to load `biblatex` just for names (middle names are quite rare in French).