# Best practices for setting package options mid-document

Tags: expl3, best-practices, package-writing, package-options

I am currently working on a package where the user can set the package options mid-document or within a local group. Currently, the user can do this via the user commands `\set<package>keys` or `\reset<package>keys`, which first resets the package options back to the defaults before setting the new options. I intend these commands to be used only at the document level; they should not be used directly in the preamble.

My question is: What is the best practice for naming these commands? My confusion comes from another stack exchange thread
[Package option vs setup command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/434514/package-option-vs-setup-command)
where the top answer recommends that the package author provide a user command named `\<package>setup`. Additionally, many other packages follow the same convention: `siunitx` uses `\sisetup`, `unicode-math` uses `\unimathsetup`, `microtype` uses `\microtypesetup`, etc. However, I find that the name `\package<setup>` implies, contrary to my current package, that (1) `\<package>setup` can/should be used directly in the preamble and (2) `\<package>setup` sets up the package options *globally* rather than *locally*.

I add the tag `expl3` to my question because I am currently writing a package in `expl3`. Also the package options are defined via `l3keys` and `\ProcessKeyOptions`.

Comment: they aren't really package options if used in the document after the package is loaded, they are simply keys used by a command defined by that package so I'm not sure there is a general naming scheme to follow, it depends on the details of the command

Comment: No, the `setup` macros usually don't act globally (and why would they? Acting locally works better). The name is just a loosely followed convention. Take a look at other bigger packages and you got `\KOMAoptions`, or `\tikzset`, etc. Though the advantage of the `<package>setup` name is ease of memory. In the end you're to decide on the name. But I really don't see your point about the command not being usable in the preamble. Depending on what your options are about, not everything is easily entered as a package option due to the expansion implications that has.

Comment: @Skillmon, I worry about twice processing the package keys which may increase compilation times.

Comment: @User23456234 then drop any package processing and only provide `setup`, et voila, you only process them once. Or you still provide both, and any user using both in the preamble gets what he wants, and any user not using both doesn't get what he wants. But not allowing `setup` in the preamble seems just weird and limiting.

Comment: your question really isn't clear enough to answer, but with the new option processing, using `\usepackage` twice, with different options is no longer an error but the second call essentially just runs the setup command to process the keys without re-inputing the file. The processing is usually local (despite your comment) but at the top level so has global effect. There is essentially no cost to processing keys that are not used so it is not clear (as you have provided no examples in comments or in the question) what you mean by "I worry about twice processing the package keys"

Comment: Oh, also, in practice package options are slower to process than options provided to a `setup` macro, so if you worry about performance...

Comment: @Skillmon, are there any other disadvantages to making package keys available both via package options and `\<package>setup`?

Comment: The only disadvantages I really see is having to keep track which values have to be set during package loading and which might be changed later on, but that can be handled via the `.usage:n`-property, so isn't too hard. That and the expansion problem for package options (because they automatically get used inside an `\edef`, regardless of whether you use the new raw keys via `\ProcessKeyOptions` or `expkv-opt` (or other means), or the old system).